# Connect a 3rd screen to a tight Mini-ITX case

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hdmi, computer-building, mini-itx

I have an *AMD Ryzen 5 2400G* with integrated Vega graphics on an *MSI B350I Pro AC* mini ITX mainboard in an *InWin Chopin* case. It's a tight fit.

I'm trying to connect 3 screens. There is an HDMI and a DisplayPort output already on the motherboard. One option for the 3rd screen would be an external USB to HDMI graphics card.

However, there is also a carve-out in the case [green] right in-line with the PCI slot [red].
There is barely room between the carve-out and the lid of the case, and the PCI slot and the integrated PSU.

Is it possible to use the PCI slot to gain an additional HDMI output for the 3rd screen? How and which type of card would fit the slot? 
Is there yet another alternative?

[image]
[image]